# restoreCompletedTransactions function doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am currently testing my app with sandbox. Purchase works and I can see that delegate functions are being called. When I call

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

I don't get any response from following delegate methods

```
  // Delegate Methods

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction in transactions as! [SKPaymentTransaction] {
        println("Transaction state: \(transaction.transactionState)")
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .Purchased:
            completeTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .Failed:
            failedTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .Restored:
            println("Restore DELEGATE")
            restoreTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .Purchasing:
            println("Purchasing!")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

    func restoreTransaction(transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {
        println("Restore transaction!!!!!!!!")
        if transaction.payment != nil && transaction.payment.productIdentifier != nil {
            let productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
            println(productID)
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("productPurchased", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

    }


    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError!) {

        println("Error occured during RESTORE")


    }
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("Restore Finished transactions: \(queue.transactions)")

        for transaction in queue.transactions as! [SKPaymentTransaction] {
            var productIdentifier = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
            println("Restored: \(productIdentifier)")

        }

    }
```

Is it because of Sandbox? Is there anyway for me to test whether restore is working or not? Thanks

**EDIT:** It was all my my fault. Code is working. iPhone I was testing on, had a tweak called LocalAPStore and it seems it was blocking restore. Anyway at least I learned that my verification code works even user has some hack installed.

Comment: What type of IAP are you trying to restore?

Comment: Non consumable. However yesterday I have found out that, Phone I was testing on was jailbroken and had some inapp purchasing hack. I pulled my hair many times :) It is working now.